# ASP.NET Web API: Get client id on preflight request

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2, preflight

I've enabled CORS in my ASP.NET Web API project and I need a way to identify the user making a preflight request. This is because each client has their own allowed origin.

Here's what my `CorsPolicyProvider` looks like:

```cs
public class MyCorsPolicyProvider : ICorsPolicyProvider {

    private CorsPolicy _policy;

    public MyCorsPolicyProvider() {
        _policy = new CorsPolicy {
            AllowAnyMethod= true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true
        };
    }

    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        var clientId = ""; // How do I get this? Getting the user name or any way to uniquely identify the user is fine.
        Client client = ClientManager.FindClient(clientId);

        if (client != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(client.AllowedOrigin)) {
            _policy.Origins.Add(client.AllowedOrigin);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(_policy);
    }
}
```

My preflight request doesn't contain any information about the user, so I'm not sure this is possible. But it seems to me like this is a common scenario, no? It would be ideal if I had access to my claims, but obviously we don't know anything about the user at this point. Am I approaching this wrong?